# How to get target of running transition in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, url-routing

How can I get current transition final target (route name) when transition is in progress.

Consider following scenario: I have route `route` of resource `resource`. Transitioning to `resource.route` was executed. I would like to get target route name when `resource` model hook is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is `activeTransition` on `router` which has reference to target route:

```
Route = Ember.Route.extend({

  router: Ember.inject.service('-router'),

  model: function() {
    var target = this.get('router.router.activeTransition.targetName');
    if (target === 'credentials.signin') {
      // do something
    } else {
      // do something else
    }
  }

});
```